# SQL query that does not exist Phpmyadmin

Tags: sql

I am writing a SQL query to show me the following:

1. Results that have `_go_product_url` in the `meta_key` and that is not null.
2. And I need it to only show me in the results based on the first query that do not have the meta_key `_go_product_info`

What would be the best method without spending a lot of resources on the server?

I am working with Wordpress. But for now testing in phpmyadmin

I ran this query but without results

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%_go_product_url%' 
  AND `meta_value` IS NOT NULL 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` 
                  WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%_go_product_info%' IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You presumably want to identify posts meeting these criteria, so you should be selecting something like the `post_id` and/or the other columns you want.  Here is one aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING SUM(meta_key LIKE '%_go_product_url%') > 0 AND
       SUM(meta_key LIKE '%_go_product_info%') = 0;
```